# How to block input of numbers from list?

Tags: python

```
FirstNumber = int(input('Input first odd number smaller than17:'))
SecondNumber = int(input('Input second odd number smaller than 17:'))
SumOfBoth = FirstNumber + SecondNumber
listN = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]

if int(FirstNumber or SecondNumber) <= 17:
    print(SumOfBoth)



elif  (FirstNumber or SecondNumber) > 17:
    print('Error')
```

As you can see in my program I created a list called "ListN", can u help me, when user writes a number and press enter, to make the program not accept the numbers from the list.

Comment: Pls guys can u help me

Comment: do you want to take input until a correct value is entered?

Comment: I dont want people to input number from list like 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 .....

Comment: Your conditionals don't do what you think.  You could use `if FirstNumber  <= 17 and FirstNumber  % 2 == 1 and SecondNumber <= 17 and SecondNumber % 2 == 1 : print(SumOfBoth)` (i.e. FirstNumber % 2 == 1 checks that FirstNumber is odd--which is better than `not FirstNumber in listN` for checking for odd.

Comment: I mean you can't explicitly stop the user from entering a particular value , though you can display a error message or just take input again and again until the value entered statisfies the condition

Comment: Darry IG it worked thank u

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
if FirstNumber not in listN:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Wrong Input")
```